# Font Awesome icon in language override Joomla 3.8.11

Tags: joomla, font-awesome, joomla3.0

Hello I have been playing with overrides and I decided to make language overrides for pagination Next and Previous Text buttons but the issue is when I make language override using for example:
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
<i title="Next article" class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i>
```

or 
plain

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I get the icon but also get **">** displayed in front of it.

[Screenshot for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKtSr.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check your tags and attributes inside the tags if they are properly closed, e.g. there can be some mistake like

```
<i title="Next article" class="fa fa-fast-forward">"></i>
```

Comment: No this is not an issue as I have found out that double quotation in language strings are not allowing another set of  " inside translation strings and Joomla strips them.